# Why does std::uncaught_exception return false when LuaJIT throws?

Tags: c++, exception, luajit

The LuaJIT manual [states](http://luajit.org/extensions.html):

> Lua errors can be caught on the C++ side with catch(...). The corresponding Lua error message can be retrieved from the Lua stack.

This works as intended - except that `std::uncaught_exception()` does not return true in this case.

Following is a minimal example to illustrate the issue. The destructor of `checker` should be executed during stack unwinding and thus `std::uncaught_exception()` in it should return true, but it does not.

How can this be? Am I misunderstanding the process or does LuaJIT perform the exception raising in a sketchy way?

```
struct checker {
    ~checker() {
        if(std::uncaught_exception()) {
            // condition should evaluate true, but doesn't
        }
    }
}

auto l = luaL_newstate();
try {
    {
        checker c;
        luaL_checknumber(l, -1); // this line causes LuaJIT to raise an error
    }
}
catch(...) {
    // this will be executed, as intended
    auto err = lua_tostring(state, -1); // read the LuaJIT error, works too
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @immibis OSX 10.11.5, `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.31)`

Comment: Uncaught exception is looking for a C++ exception, while `catch(...)` is also spotting lua ones.

Comment: @Yakk [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) describes the function as: `[...] std::uncaught_exception detects if stack unwinding is currently in progress.` - To me this reads like it is not limited to exception types.

Comment: @Appleshell: Be advised that `uncaught_exception` [has issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2475138/734069), which is why C++17 replaces it with uncaught_exception***s***.

Comment: @apple sure, but you are interacting with non-C++ compliant runtime code (lua).  It isn;t following the C++ runtime rules...

Comment: @Yakk Well, LuaJIT [*does* call internal C++ runtime exception handling / DWARF2 functions](https://github.com/LuaDist/luajit/blob/master/src/lj_err.c#L304) for the exception interoperability. That it does so in an incomplete manner is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

**Original Lua** (not LuaJIT) uses C-style exceptions (long jumps) that are not C++ exceptions.
`grep` Lua sources for LUAI_THROW and notice the difference between C/C++ exception handling.

```
/*
@@ LUAI_THROW/LUAI_TRY define how Lua does exception handling.
** CHANGE them if you prefer to use longjmp/setjmp even with C++
** or if want/don't to use _longjmp/_setjmp instead of regular
** longjmp/setjmp. By default, Lua handles errors with exceptions when
** compiling as C++ code, with _longjmp/_setjmp when asked to use them,
** and with longjmp/setjmp otherwise.
*/
#if defined(__cplusplus)
/* C++ exceptions */
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) throw(c)
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) try { a } catch(...) \
    { if ((c)->status == 0) (c)->status = -1; }
#define luai_jmpbuf int  /* dummy variable */

#elif defined(LUA_USE_ULONGJMP)
/* in Unix, try _longjmp/_setjmp (more efficient) */
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) _longjmp((c)->b, 1)
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) if (_setjmp((c)->b) == 0) { a }
#define luai_jmpbuf jmp_buf

#else
/* default handling with long jumps */
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) longjmp((c)->b, 1)
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) if (setjmp((c)->b) == 0) { a }
#define luai_jmpbuf jmp_buf

#endif
```

I'm not sure that it is possible, but you may try to compile Lua with C++ and this will allow you to catch Lua exceptions.
Note, original Lua compiled as C code does not support C++ stack frames unwinding!

As for **LuaJIT** it looks like it implements frame unwinding itself, see lj_err.c for more info. That's why some CRT variables may not be set during this process.

```
/*
** LuaJIT can either use internal or external frame unwinding:
**
** - Internal frame unwinding (INT) is free-standing and doesn't require
**   any OS or library support.
**
** - External frame unwinding (EXT) uses the system-provided unwind handler.
**
** Pros and Cons:
**
** - EXT requires unwind tables for *all* functions on the C stack between
**   the pcall/catch and the error/throw. This is the default on x64,
**   but needs to be manually enabled on x86/PPC for non-C++ code.
**
** - INT is faster when actually throwing errors (but this happens rarely).
**   Setting up error handlers is zero-cost in any case.
**
** - EXT provides full interoperability with C++ exceptions. You can throw
**   Lua errors or C++ exceptions through a mix of Lua frames and C++ frames.
**   C++ destructors are called as needed. C++ exceptions caught by pcall
**   are converted to the string "C++ exception". Lua errors can be caught
**   with catch (...) in C++.
**
** - INT has only limited support for automatically catching C++ exceptions
**   on POSIX systems using DWARF2 stack unwinding. Other systems may use
**   the wrapper function feature. Lua errors thrown through C++ frames
**   cannot be caught by C++ code and C++ destructors are not run.
**
** EXT is the default on x64 systems, INT is the default on all other systems.
**
** EXT can be manually enabled on POSIX systems using GCC and DWARF2 stack
** unwinding with -DLUAJIT_UNWIND_EXTERNAL. *All* C code must be compiled
** with -funwind-tables (or -fexceptions). This includes LuaJIT itself (set
** TARGET_CFLAGS), all of your C/Lua binding code, all loadable C modules
** and all C libraries that have callbacks which may be used to call back
** into Lua. C++ code must *not* be compiled with -fno-exceptions.
**
** EXT cannot be enabled on WIN32 since system exceptions use code-driven SEH.
** EXT is mandatory on WIN64 since the calling convention has an abundance
** of callee-saved registers (rbx, rbp, rsi, rdi, r12-r15, xmm6-xmm15).
** EXT is mandatory on POSIX/x64 since the interpreter doesn't save r12/r13.
*/
```

P.S. I think you are already aware of safe Lua type checks (`lua_is*`), and safe functions like `lua_pcall`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::uncaught_exception` is a function of the C++ exception handling mechanism. What LuaJIT is doing *is not* the C++ exception handling mechanism. LuaJIT did not issue a `throw`. It simply used hidden system calls to mimic the behavior of the exception handling mechanism. But like any facade, it is only an imitation, not the real thing.

Imagine that the C++ code "throw X();" is converted into the following:

```
auto thrown = x();
auto handler = find_handle_for_exception(thrown);
if(!handler) std::terminate();
auto except = allocate_exception(thrown);
handling_exception = true;
unwind_stack_to_handler(handler);
handling_exception = false;
handler(except); //Transfers control to handler.
```

LuaJIT comes along and it knows about all of these hidden, internal system calls. So when it wants to "throw" an exception, it does this:

```
auto handler = find_handle_for_exception(); //Only matches ...
if(!handler) std::terminate();
unwind_stack_to_handler(handler);
handler(); //Transfers control to handler.
```

In this pseudo-code, `uncaught_exception` works by reading the value of `handling_exception`. But woopsie, LuaJIT didn't update that variable in its version of throwing. Probably because it's new to C++11, and they never bothered to check to see how that part worked on the various systems. Or maybe it does work on some systems, but not MacOSX.

That's always a danger when you try to emulate some functionality that your abstraction provides. That you won't do it in a perfectly interoperable way. I have no idea why LuaJIT couldn't just throw a real C++ exception like normal people...

Comment: Appreciate the insight. I guess I'll have to turn to the mailing list to see if it's possible to honour `std::uncaught_exception` in a future update, after I've tested this on other platforms. (Just a note, it looks like it's not new to C++11 but existed since C++98 ;)